# I want a reference to find all properties of event.target

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I am learning JS and I have a function that has an event (e) as a parameter 
now I could access the target using e.target but now I want to see all the different style attributes in e.target.style ( IN MDN PAGE ) but I could not find the page. Can someone help me finding the page.

Comment: Maybe this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately your question doesn't fit this site, and I have voted to put it on hold due to: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] pages in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by logging the `event` in the console and then finding the `target` key.

Alternatively you can also use `window.getComputedStyle`

```js
function getAllProps(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<button type='button' onclick='getAllProps(event)'>Click</button>
```